# Query a record between two dates, where dates might be 1900-01-01

Tags: sql, date, datetime

Imagine this. You need to query your pricing data table to find out what the current pricing is on a part number given a specific date. You table is formatted so that if the 'from date' is `'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'` and your 'to date' is `'2021-06-07 00:00:00.000'`, then that means any date before the 'to date' is valid.

There is also another record with 'from date' `2021-06-08 00:00:00.000` to `'1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'`, which means anything after the date.

Here is the table visually

| itemrelation | fromdate | todate | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A123456 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2021-06-07 00:00:00.000 | 1578.300000000000 |
| A123456 | 2021-06-08 00:00:00.000 | 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 1586.300000000000 |

Lets say the user wants to check what the price is today `2022-03-24`

The query ran cannot be

```
SELECT itemrelation, fromdate, todate, amount
  FROM [Ax2009Live].[dbo].[PRICEDISCTABLE] 
  where itemrelation = 'A123456'
  and fromDate <= '2022-03-24'
  and toDate >= '2022-03-24'
```

because of the "1900" dates will prevent the query from returning any results.

Is there some type of CASE statement that would work to solve this problem? Some built in SQL command I don't know about?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I absolutely hate it when people do that, if you want `NULL`, use `NULL` not `1900-01-01` (I'm not blaming you, but it does frustrate me). To solve, you can do something like `and (toDate >= '2022-03-24' or toDate = '1900-01-01')`

Comment: If you are going to use a date, instead of null, in your  toDate then at least choose a date in the future (e.g. 2999-01-01) so that your data makes logical sense

Comment: @HoneyBadger , Yes I do too, its an Axapta database/table. AX does not use null values at all (in tables at least).

Comment: You can compare against `case when toDate = '1900-01-01' then '2154-12-31' else toDate end` I have no idea if that's the most officient way of dealing with this and I got that max date value here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @HoneyBadger,

Here is the query based on your suggestion. It works great.

```
DECLARE @ITEMRELATION AS NVARCHAR(50)
SET @ITEMRELATION = 'A123456'

DECLARE @DATE AS DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2022-03-24'

SELECT itemrelation, fromdate, todate, amount
  FROM [Ax2009Live].[dbo].[PRICEDISCTABLE] 
  WHERE 
  itemrelation = @ITEMRELATION
  and fromDate <= @DATE
  and toDate >= @DATE
  OR 
  itemrelation = @ITEMRELATION
  and fromDate <= @DATE
  and toDate = '1900-01-01'
  OR 
  itemrelation = @ITEMRELATION
  and fromDate = '1900-01-01'
  and toDate >= @DATE
```

Comment: Glad you got it working. When mixing AND/OR conditions, it is always advisable (even if just to make it easier to read) to use parantheses: `WHERE (condition1 AND condition2) OR (condition3 AND condition4)`